# fire function on hover area

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

I'm trying to fire a function only when you roll over the red area.

http://jsfiddle.net/yAwJ2/

Any advice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#wrapper").bind('mousemove', function(e) {
        $("#tail").css({
            top: e.pageY
        });
    });
});
```

Added: To back to the start position:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#wrapper").hover(function() {
        $.data(this, "tail_Y", $("#tail").css("top"));
    }, function() {
        $("#tail").css("top", $.data(this, "tail_Y"));
    }).bind('mousemove', function(e) {
        $("#tail").css({
            top: e.pageY
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1stein/VWEEB/

Comment: Fantastic, is there a way for the tail to snap back to the original position? Would you remove the CSS function when you mouseout?

Answer (score 0):

may this help

```
$(document).bind('mousemove', function(e){
    $('#tail').css({
       top:   e.pageY
    });
    $('#wrapper').click(function(){    
    xyz();

     });
});


function xyz()
{
        alert('hello');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#wrapper").mouseover(function() {
   // your function here
   alert("mouse over red area");
});
```

[**Example fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/yAwJ2/36/)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to make sure you run this code once the dom is ready:

```
$("#wrapper").bind('mouseenter', function(e) {
   alert("Entered Wrapper")
});
```